# displaying total net income, double values wont appear

Tags: java, swing

my total income wont appear. I calculate all the different deductions and all the buttons work and the value appears. But for my final button that calculates the net income, the values wont appear. I do not get any values when i run it.

How can i get the final values of eg PRSI,  tax credits, in each of the action listeners and use them for my final button which is to calculate the net income.

Heres my full code it is the net button that wont work.

I just want the net income to appear at the end.

```
    // Net income
    net.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent en) {
        String line = "";   
            double grossENt = Double.parseDouble(gross.getText());

            netin = grossENt -((totalTax+ PRSI + uscTotal) - allcredit);

         line = line +" Net income" + netin;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you share your code which do not work?

Comment: Re your edit - You're missing out a lot of code there. So you've put something in `line`...what do you *do* with it?

Comment: ive added all of my code ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fundamental problem is that you're populating a local `line` variable, but never using it for anything:

```
// Net income
net.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent en) {
    String line = "";                     // <=============== It's a local
        double grossENt = Double.parseDouble(gross.getText());

        netin = grossENt -((totalTax+ PRSI + uscTotal) - allcredit);

     line = line +" Net income" + netin; // <================ You never do anything with it
    }
});
```

In other listeners in your code where you have this local `line` variable, you generally end the listener with:

```
statementTextArea.append(line);
```

Perhaps you want to do that in the above as well.

Comment: Thank you so much ive been sitting here for an  hour trying to figure it out. Didnt see that.